# querying ldap server with java unboundid-ldapsdk

Tags: java, ldap, ldap-query, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I have setup an ldap server with Apache director studio:
[image]

This is my code:

```
import com.unboundid.asn1.ASN1OctetString;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.*;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.controls.SimplePagedResultsControl;
public class App {

      /**
       * @param args
       * @throws LDAPException 
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) throws LDAPException {


        LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection("localhost", 10389, "uid=admin,ou=system","secret");//"cn=admin4directory,dc=ilex-si,dc=eu", "M3d2p5a4!");

        //SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("ou=people,dc=ilex-si,dc=eu", SearchScope.SUB,"(ixuid=*)");
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("ou=people,dc=example,dc=com", SearchScope.BASE,Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectClass", "person"));

        ASN1OctetString cookie = null;
       do
       {
         searchRequest.setControls(
              new Control[] { new SimplePagedResultsControl(500, cookie) });
         SearchResult searchResult = connection.search(searchRequest);

         // Do something with the entries that are returned.

         cookie = null;
         for (Control c : searchResult.getResponseControls())
         {
           if (c instanceof SimplePagedResultsControl)
           {
             cookie = ((SimplePagedResultsControl) c).getCookie();
             System.out.println("\ncookie = "+ cookie.toString());
           }
         }
       } while ((cookie != null) && (cookie.getValueLength() > 0));


       connection.close();

      }

    }
```

I want to do a paged query but with this code I have returned a blank cookie..
How can I print the cn = john smit and cn robert smith values??

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>it.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>LDAPPagedQueryExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>LDAPPagedQueryExample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
    <build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
        <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>     
            <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>  
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the simple example at https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/controls/SimplePagedResultsControl.html

For sure You [SearchScope.BASE](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/SearchScope.html) must be at LEAST SearchScope.ONE or better SearchScope.SUB.

Not sure what is implied "How can I print the cn = john smit and cn robert smith values??"